# Can this async/await code be rewritten using Task.WhenAll(...) or something else that makes more sense then awaiting each time?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have the following piece of code (changed the names of my classes/objects for brevity). It essentially is hitting an external API that allows only a single operation, but my service code will expose it as a `bulk` type request.

It doesn't seem right to await on each async request, but instead dispatch all the requests and just wait for all of them. I could be wrong tho.

```
public async void SendSeveralRequestsAsync(MyClass myClass)
{
   var client = SomeExternalServiceClient();

   foreach(var item in myClass)
   {
        var singleAsyncRequest = new ExternalServiceRequest()
        {
            Value = item.Value
        };

        var response = await client.SendAsync(singleAsyncRequest);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use something like:

```
public async void SendSeveralRequestsAsync(MyClass myClass)
{
   var client = SomeExternalServiceClient();
   var tasks = myClass
       .Select(item => new ExternalServiceRequest { Value = item.Value })
       .Select(request => client.SendAsync(request));
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Or perhaps even better - as I don't like returning `void` from an async method other than for events:

```
public Task SendSeveralRequestsAsync(MyClass myClass)
{
   var client = SomeExternalServiceClient();
   var tasks = myClass
       .Select(item => new ExternalServiceRequest { Value = item.Value })
       .Select(request => client.SendAsync(request));
   return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```